# Identification of IC used in Pololu 5V, 5A Buck Converter (my2101 330)

Tags: power-electronics, identification, buck, buck-boost

I have identified the chip on the Pololu 5V, 5A buck converter as my2101 330, but I am having difficulty finding information about this chip on any platform. I've checked the Pololu resources page ([www.pololu.com/product/2851/resources](http://www.pololu.com/product/2851/resources)), but the datasheet is not available there.

Could someone please guide me on where I can find the datasheet for the my2101 330 chip or provide relevant information about its specifications? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "M" symbol looks like Micrel's logo before they got bought up my Microchip. Example: -

[image]

Above right-side image from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/electronic-components/datasheet/MIC59P60BWM--Micrel/). Left-side from question.

So, I guess the device might be a [MIC2101](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC2101_02-38V-Synchronous-Buck-Controllers-Featuring-Adaptive-ON-Time-Control-DS20005922B.pdf). Microchip have this as a buck converter in the same package shape: -

[image]

I'm not saying it definitely is the device on the Polulu module but, it's worth further investigation. Packaging ID information looks similar (note the "Y"): -

[image]